# How do I use 'StartTranscriptionJobRequest' from the AWS Transcribe C++ API?

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-transcribe

I am having some difficulty with AWS Transcribe for C++. I believe a simple code example would solve it for me, but I find no code examples of the AWS Transcribe API in C++, (I realize there is one for [TranscribeStreamingService](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/real-time-streaming-transcription-with-the-aws-c-sdk/), but my task is far simpler.)

According to the AWS docs for [TranscribeServiceClient](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/cpp/api/LATEST/class_aws_1_1_transcribe_service_1_1_transcribe_service_client.html) and [StartTranscriptionJobRequest](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/cpp/api/LATEST/class_aws_1_1_transcribe_service_1_1_model_1_1_start_transcription_job_request.html) I need to create a `StartTranscriptionJobRequest` object, fill it in with setters, and hand it to the `TranscribeServiceClient` like this:

```
#include <aws/core/Aws.h>
#include <aws/core/auth/AWSCredentialsProviderChain.h>
#include <aws/core/client/AWSClient.h>
#include <aws/transcribe/TranscribeServiceClient.h>

using namespace Aws;
using namespace Aws::TranscribeService;
using namespace Aws::TranscribeService::Model;

void TestAWSTranscript() {

    Aws::SDKOptions options;
    Aws::InitAPI(options);
    {
        Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration config;

        TranscribeServiceClient TranscriptClient(Auth::AWSCredentials(user_access_key.c_str(), user_private_key.c_str()), config);

        StartTranscriptionJobRequest request = new StartTranscriptionJobRequest();
        // request.SetLanguageCode(Aws::TranscribeService::Model::LanguageCode::en_US);
        // more setters here...

        TranscriptClient.StartTranscriptionJob(&request);
        // check for completion
        // enjoy transcript...

    }
    Aws::ShutdownAPI(options);
}
```

but the line:

```
StartTranscriptionJobRequest request = new StartTranscriptionJobRequest();
```

produces the errors:

```
Allocation of incomplete type 'Aws::TranscribeService::Model::StartTranscriptionJobRequest'
Variable has incomplete type 'Aws::TranscribeService::Model::StartTranscriptionJobRequest'
```

If it helps, the aws sdk is open-source and [available](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/tree/master/aws-cpp-sdk-transcribe) on git.

What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*incomplete type* means the complete class definition is not available/the class is only [forward declared](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class#Forward_declaration).

adding
`#include <aws/transcribe/model/StartTranscriptionJobRequest.h>`
should fix this

Comment: I would +1 you but I lack the cred.